# How to remove a keybinding

Tags: zsh, key-bindings

So I have zsh installed and when i run the command:

```
bindkey | grep kill-word
```

I see the following results:

```
"^W" backward-kill-word
"^[^H" backward-kill-word
"^[D" kill-word
"^[d" kill-word
"^[^?" backward-kill-word
```

I want to remove some of these key bindings, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Say you wanted to remove the lower case version of `kill-word`. `bindkey -r` will remove the given binding.

```
bindkey -r '\ed'
```